# Sort a large unordered output file to the order of the input file

Tags: sorting

I am running a multi-threaded program which takes an ordered by id input file, but in the output file the ids are unordered. There are millions of ids and the output file is gigabytes in size.

The output looks like:

@55540
GTGTCTAGTTTAATTTGCCTGCATGTGGATATCCATTTTTCCCAGCATCATTTATTGAAGAGACTCTCTTTTCCCCTCTGTAGATTCTTGGCACCTCTGC
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
GTGTCTAGTTTAATTTGCCTGCATGTGGATATCCATTTTTCCCAGCATCATTTATTGAAGAGACTCTCTTTTCCCCTCTGTAGATTCTTGGCACCTCTGC
CL100097983L1C001R035_550287/1:1(+) Q40, 100.0% id

@55469
CACGGAATTACTGTATGACCCAGCAATTCTACTCCAAGAGAAATGAAAATACACGTCCACACAAAAACATGTACATGAATGTTCATAGTAGCATTATCTG
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
CACGGAATTACTGTATGACCCAGCAATTCTACTCCAAGAGAAATGAAAATACACGTCCACACAAAAACATGTACATGAATGTTCATAGTAGCATTATCTG
CL100097983L1C001R002_909/1:1(+) Q40, 100.0% id

@55703
ATATTCCCAAGAGAAAGGGTGAAGGGATGCAAAACAGACAGAGAGATGCCACTTGACAAGGGTTCTCATGGCCAAGGTCAGCCATTGCATCTTCAATCAC
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
ATATTCCCAAGAGAAAGGGTGAAGGGATGCAAAACAGACAGAGAGATGCCACTTGACAAGGGTTCTCATGGCCAAGGTCAGCCATTGCATCTTCAATCAC
CL100097983L1C001R035_550309/1:1(+) Q40, 100.0% id

Two approaches, 1) sort the output using python running in parallel. Single thread python would require more than a year to sort the file.
2) To modify the original program so it outputs only in the order it read the input. This would require some threads to wait until others have finished their process.

The thread management for approach 2 looks like a nightmare for 32 threads, but this would still be faster than any post processing of the output file.

Any hints on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest upload to a cloud solution and pay for compute. For example Databricks

Comment: Exactly how would a cloud solution solve my sorting problem? The issue isn't computer resources. It is sorting these huge files in a timely manner, or modifying the c++ program which generates this output, to have the output match the order of the input.

Comment: To get required processing time you can spend $ on developer time optimising algorithms or you can spend $ on computer resources. Sometimes it's more cost effective and less risky to throw computer resources at it. Sorting algorithms aren't anything new. You appear to be custom writing something to do this. If you were to do this on spark for example it's more declarative and it's more about getting data spread across enough nodes to do the operation in parallel. There's no thread management required.